# EaselJS triangle with rounded corners?

Tags: javascript, easeljs

How can I create a triangle with rounded corners in EaselJS? I'm using drawPolyStar to create the triangle,

```
var polystar = new createjs.Shape();
polystar.graphics.drawPolyStar(100, 100, 60, 3, 0, -90);
```

This is an image of what I want the triangle to look like: [image: Outcome vs Expected triangle]

EDIT: Image link doesn't seem to work. This is what the triangle should look like : [image]

But actual triangle has sharp corners.

Comment: I can not open the image

Comment: @OptimusCrime Yeah. Updated with another image.

Answer (score 0):

There are no canvas APIs for rounding corners of polygons that works like the roundRect API.

There are a few approaches I can think of:

1. Do the round corners yourself using arcTo. This would take some math to figure out, and there may even be some libraries or examples floating around.

[EDIT] I spent a little time making a sample https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/cga60tsf/1/

2. Using rounded stroke edges, you can sort of fake it. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHCJt/1673/) shows how a thick line with round ends can make the outer edges look round. You could draw another smaller triangle on top to give the desired effect.

Sample

```
// Line outer radius
context.lineJoin = "round";
context.lineWidth = cornerRadius;
```

Comment: Spent a little time trying to figure this one out, and got a decent approximation... Its not great, but it gives you a place to start. https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/cga60tsf/1/